# How to implement multiple tag search across my image gallery with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image gallery with search input , where the user can type image title or image tag and search for matches. I now need to be able to have multiple search for the tags. For example if i type : #tree - > the result will be all the images that have "tree" in their tags (specifically ) , not the ones that partially contains the word, as Tag search should be specific. I need to be able to type : #tree,#sky - > and the output to be all the images that have  "tree" and "sky" in them . So far my code executes only the first example .

HTML :

```
<div class="searchBtn">
    <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Search by name or #tag">
    <button onclick="Search()" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let filterSearch = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();

function findAllImages(filter, start, itemsCount) {  
    let photos = [];
    let tagSign = "#";
    const searchByTag = filterSearch [0] === tagSign;
    let searchCondition = searchByTag ? filterSearch.slice(1) : filter;

       let newFiltered = imageArrayPhotos.filter(
    searchByTag ? image =>  image.tag.indexOf(searchCondition) >= 0 :
        image => image.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchCondition) >= 0);

for (let i = start; i < newFiltered.length; i++) {
    photos .push(newFiltered [i]);

    if (photos.length >= numberOfImages) {
        break;
    }
}
return photos ;
}
```

Can i do it with a callback function on `let newFiltered = imageArrayPhotos.filter(function() {})` that goes through all the possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `regex`. check if this is feasible.

```js
let searchByTag = true;
let imageArrayPhotos = [{
    tag: 'tree',
    title: 'tree'
  },
  {
    tag: 'forest',
    title: 'tree'
  },
  {
    tag: 'sky',
    title: 'sky'
  },
  {
    tag: 'bird',
    title: 'bird'
  },
  {
    tag: 'watertree',
    title: 'sky'
  },
];

let filterSearch = '';
let searchCondition = '';
let pattern;
let newFiltered = [];

function Search() {
  newFiltered = [];
  filterSearch = '';
  searchCondition = '';
  filterSearch = $("#inputValue").val();
  filterSearch = filterSearch.split(',');
  //searchCondition = searchByTag ? filterSearch.slice(1) : filter;
  //newFiltered = imageArrayPhotos.filter(checkFilter);
  filterSearch.forEach(function(item) {
    item = $.trim(item);
    searchByTag = item[0] == "#";
    pattern = new RegExp("^" + $.trim(item).replace(/#/g, '') + "$");

    let itemData = imageArrayPhotos.filter(checkFilter);
    if (itemData.length > 0) {
      newFiltered = newFiltered.concat(itemData);
    }

  });
  console.log(newFiltered);
}

function checkFilter(image) {
  return searchByTag ? pattern.test(image.tag) :
    pattern.test(image.title)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchBtn">
  <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Search by name or #tag">
  <button onclick="Search()" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , can you explain the regex ? What exactly `( /, /g , ' | ')` means  and `( /#/g, ' ')` as well ? As if i make both patterns to be as the titlePatt it works , but it is not case sensitive for the tag ( it finds the tags that contain the word partially as well  and i need it to be specific) . Thank you for your time

Comment: Updated the code and those regex to replace the `,` with `|` as regular expression treats pipes for separation of expression. and you were transforming the input text to lower so it was taking the both input as lower and matching it.

Comment: But how can i make it the regexp for the tag , to search specifically for that tag , and exclude those that contain partial of that word , for example : #dog - > dog , and not #dog - > dog, underdog etc...

Comment: Hi again @Rohit.007 , any idea how can i make it the regexp for the tag , to search specifically for that tag , and exclude those that contain partial of that word , for example : #dog - > dog , and not #dog - > dog, underdog etc...

Comment: That already been taken care. this will find the the exact tag, if you find #dog it will find the #dog only in tags and not the #underdog, I have already added the example of #tree and #watertree

Comment: yes ,i saw ,sorry for my question , but with that code, if my tags are : cat,animal - > and i type in the search field #cat, it does not find the image . If "cat" tag is the second item (animal,cat) , then it finds it . IS there any reason for that ?

Comment: Actually there is a condition in your code to either find in tag or title, so currently it is not finding in title but we can make such code where it will find the text with #(hash) in tag and non hashed in title

Comment: Will it be with regex again ?

Comment: this is the current condition `searchCondition = searchByTag ? filterSearch.slice(1) : filter;` and you can find it in both just by removing the searchByTag condition and place a OR based condition in `return searchByTag ? tagPatt.test(image.tag) :
    titlePatt.test(image.title)`

Comment: Maybe there is a way with FOR loop ? As the regex matches only if there is one image tag , otherwise maybe we can implement somewhere `(/w+)/g` .

Comment: Yes that can be achieve by forloop but that will not the optimized way but for your concern, regex do match the multiple tags e.g. #bird,#tree

Comment: For some reason , not in my code . I will add a snippet here https://i.imgur.com/JvMZIew.png . 
There is difference to the naming of the variables and function , but i think the other thing is the same . I have no  `searchCondition` , and made the regesTitle, case insensitive and it works perfectly.The tag search works , only if the tag is at the last position in the tag array.

Comment: And in addition my tags in the  `arrayPhotos` , does not have "#" infront of them. You have made them `tag: '#bird'` , mine is `tag: 'bird'`  and it needs to be kept that way.

Comment: If i make it with For loop , should i use the regex again ?

Comment: Is it posssible to show me how it will be done with For loop , if i am getting annoying , no need to show me , all good ;)